# How to remov installed package with Ape Python smart contract framework?

Tags: python, ape

Does anybody know how to remove package installed with `ape pm`? Brownie has `brownie ethpm remove [package-name]` Or I should just delete folder in `~/.ape/packages`?

Answer (score 1):

answer on my question: official information that I got from Ape team today (17th of August 2023) they don't have remove option for installed packages. Now they will add this as an issue and we can expecting remove functionality in some future version of Ape framework.

For now only solution is to delete package folder inside `~/.ape/package`